# How to allow normal user to access port 80 and 443 on compute engine ubuntu18.04 intance?

Tags: django, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to host django wesite on gcp compute engine ubuntu 18.04 instance. when i'm running django development server as normal user on port 80, it show error "Error: You don't have permission to access that port." But when i run same as root user, it run successfully.
I guess normal user don't have permission to access port 80 or port 443. Is there any way i can provide port access to normal user?

Comment: See [this answer.](https://serverfault.com/a/112798)

Comment: But what are you attempting to connect to that port as the "normal user"? Usually you would use Apache or nginx, which both run as their own users with the correct privileges. I do hope you're not attempting to serve a Django website with the development server.

Comment: Port numbers below 1024 require privilege (root). Only well tested and vetted software should be allowed to run on privileged ports. For your case using a web server reverse proxy such Nginx https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: @DanielRoseman i'm having same permission issue with apache2. I though by resolving user permission issue on development server will also resolve on apache2. I'm using apache2 with mod_wsgi(python3) but having same permission issue with port 80.

Comment: But you need to give some details of what you are doing. Once you've installed Apache it automatically binds to port 80. So what exactly is giving you a permission issue? Show what you have done.